# Android Studio: Dependency Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-studio-2.3

Android Studio: Unable to Resolve Dependencies for Android SDK Tools.

After upgrading android studio 2.3 I am unable to update my Android Studio Platform Tools from 25.0.3 to 25.3.1

**Attempt 1:**

[image: Unable to Resolve Depency]

**Attempt 2:**

Also when android studio gives update option at start, it gives another type of error.

[image]

**Attempt 3 (via Terminal):**

```
Umers-MacBook-Pro:bin UmerKiani$ ./sdkmanager --update
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
Error: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.
Umers-MacBook-Pro:bin UmerKiani$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set automatically check updates for canary channel in update dialog

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Canary channel is like alpha releases. Why would that help?

Comment: it resolved missing dependencies for me

Comment: It worked for me, it found 25.3.1, and then installed 25.3.2 as well

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: it worked for me too!!!!